# Visual Studio 2019 using 32-bit FileTracker with 64-bit toolset

Tags: c++, x86, linker, 64-bit, visual-studio-2019

I am building a C++ project with VS 2019 for a 64-bit debug configuration and using the 64-bit toolset (Preferred tool architecture = 64-bit in project properties), but VS calls FileTracker32.dll when linking:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Tracker.exe /a /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\FileTracker\ **FileTracker32.dll**" ...

Why is this the case? As a background, the motivation for this question is that for larger projects with many libs the linking step lasts very long and I'm wondering if this is not due to the fact that a 32-bit process handles it.

Comment: All of visual studio is still 32-bit as far as I know, it can generate 64-ibt code but the tools are 32-bit. 64-bit is unlikely to make it faster

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles, you are right that VS as a dev environment is 32-bit, but it still uses 64-bit toolsets. For one thing, there is a FileTracker64.dll alongside FileTracker32.dll